# Is it possible to change the USB connection volume?

Tags: settings, audio

At work I have my ringer volume set to 1/30 (which still seems very loud...). When I connect the USB cable to sync or charge I still get a very loud notification sound. Is it possible to reduce the volume when I plug it in? Failing that, is there a way to turn the USB connectivity sound off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I've found to turn of the "da-da-duh" sound you get when the phone connects to a power source or to Zune, is by toggling the Ring+Vibrate/Vibrate to vibrate. Its not as much of a hassle as I thought it would be. Right before I plug it in, I click the volume rocker, toggle to vibrate, plug it in, and toggle back to ring+vibrate. It take about 1.5 seconds.

The only sounds I can explicitly turn off on the HD7 are
Reminders, Key Press, Lock/Unlock, Camera Shutter and "All Other Notifications". Even shutting of "All Other Notifications" doesnt mute the usb connection sound.

I know it's not an elegant solution, but until WP7 gives us the ability to change individual volumes, this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by editing the registry (I use [wp7RootTools](http://wp7roottools.com/)):

- Using your registry editor, browse to `Current User\ControlPanel\Sounds\BatteryCharging`
- Change the value in the `InitVol` key to `0` (or whatever volume you prefer - on my phone, it was initially set to 75)

That's it! Note that you can also change the battery charging sound by altering the `Sound` key to point to a different `wma` file.