# How to disable the sound when connecting to charger or usb

Tags: functionality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to change the USB connection volume?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/458/is-it-possible-to-change-the-usb-connection-volume)

Everytime I connect my phone, it makes a sound. Is there a way to disable this? I tried to disable most options in Setting/ringtones+sounds but to no avail. My phone is Nolia Lumia 710.

Edit: If i disable "Ringer", it disables that specific sound but what else does it disable?

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain here. Currently there is no provided way to disable the sound. If you have the phone rooted I would imagine you can replace the sound made with a silent one, but I really don't recommend doing that.

Comment: Thank you for your post. If I find a better solution, I'll post it.

Comment: @GC710 please do!

Comment: I always plug in the night before sleep. So I lauch a light app. Looks like it prevents that sound.